# Using phpBB3 user_add() function

Tags: php, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm trying to use phpbb3 forums on my already existing website.
My website has its own registration system and i'm trying to use the `user_add()` so upon register the user will be registered to both the website and the forums.

The problem is that I use a class named `User` on my external webapp, and phpBB tries to create a class with the same name.

So i'm getting this:

`PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class user in /home/x/public_html/forum/includes/session.php on line 2360`

Is there any way to find a workaround for this? I really don't want to change my class name.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are PHP [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php), if you're on 5.3.

Comment: So if I wrap my webapp's ``User`` class with a namespace, will that solve the issue? Would I still have to change all references to the ``User`` class in my webapp code?

Comment: Only where you have the class code, and any place you instantiate objects from the class: `$user = new MyUserNameSpace\User;`